# How can I track down and fix the cause of an unknown CUDA error?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, error

It is happening at the very beginning of the Cycles render: `CUDA error at cuCtxCreate: Unknkown error`. I don't know how to even respond to that. It started when I added a basic glass material and a mirror material. I don't recall doing anything more than that on that file, and the iteration before it works. I tried getting rid of those materials but it still won't render. What should I do now?

[image]

I'm going to try rebuilding it from the previous iteration, but I thought maybe there was something I should know here.

- Ubuntu Budgie 17.04
- i7-4790K
- GeForce GTX 960
- Nvidia 375.66 binary driver
- Blender 2.78

Comment: Just FYI for troubleshooting sake, I changed nothing and it rendered fine on my machine (Blender 2.78c, GTX 1050 Ti, 970, and 1060).  I would definitely change the tile size to something like 240 x 270 for most efficient use of your GPU but that's not related to the error.

Comment: Works fine for me as well, driver 382.05 on GTX 960. Im running windows 10 though

Comment: No problem rendering on dual 780Ti on windows either. Check if there are any other versions of the Nvidia drivers that you can use. I had an issue at some point in linux and the solution was downgrading to a previous version.

Comment: See the last edit to this question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64613/gpu-rendering-issue-cuda-error-at-cuctxcreate-illegal-address   - Do you have any overclocking on your card?  Also: https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?251403-Unkown-CUDA-error

Comment: @bertmoog ah yes, tile size - just learned about that. But this was a render of just a still image, i wouldn't have thought it would present my machine much challenge. No, nothing is overclocked.

Comment: This is not a great time for me to be fiddling, i'm against the clock right now. So, based on the guidance above, for now i switched to the CPU as the rendering device. For these still images, that's fine.