# Blender Misaligned address in CuCtxSynchronisze

Tags: cycles-render-engine, error

I'm a beginner blender user.
I'm trying to render this simulation but almost every time I render it, it will stop rendering at some point in the render and show the "Blender Misaligned address in CuCtxSynchronisze" thing. It's not only in this one render, I've experienced this hundreds of times when I'm trying to render anything. This frustrates me, especially when I leave my laptop to render while I'm gone and come back just to find out that it stopped because of this error.
I've tried someone's advice on youtube to use a smaller Tile but it didn't work.
Informations:
I'm using CUDA to render.
Cycles engine.
My laptop: Asus TUF A15 GTX 1650, Ryzen 5 4600H, 32GB of RAM.
I tried both using Optix Denoiser and disabling denoiser. Both have this issue.
Sample count is 32-64 since this is just some test render.
1920x1080

It would be very helpful if someone can give me a solution.[image: error 1]
[image: error 2]
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I guess you're just running out of memory, try to render using the CPU instead and see whether the error persists. Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102536/cuda-error-launch-failed-in-cuctxsynchronize-and-cuctxcreate-launch-failed, https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96878/cuda-error-launch-failed-in-cuctxsynchronize-line-1372, https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/94178/rendering-with-gpu-crashed, https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64613/gpu-rendering-issue-cuda-error-at-cuctxcreate-illegal-address

Comment: It shouldn't be the memory since the dedicated GPU memory stays at around 1,3GB when I'm rendering this simulation and my GTX 1650 can handle up to 4GB.

Comment: If there is no solution then well, thanks for your advice, I will use CPU for rendering. I'm just a little upset since my GPU can render 10-20% ish faster than my CPU does.

Answer (score 1):

I figured that i can use OptiX rather than normal CUDA rendering on my GPU. So i used optix and it worked well! No pauses and even faster rendering.