# Cycles Cuda out of memory on final render but not on preview

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I am trying to render my scene (<kbd>F12</kbd>) and after two minutes I get the error shown below.

[image]

However, when I render the preview, it seems to have no problem.

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

*Using Blender 2.78c + Win10 
 Render Settings*

[image]

Let me know if any more information is needed. I'm still trying to get the hang of blender

The Blender file and [normal map](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3jk78d05ye9grj8/dirtBitmap2Material_3_Normal.tga?dl=0)

[image]

Comment: You might have run out of memory on your GPU. Try switched to CPU and see if it renders at all. If it does render you need more ram on your GPU.

Comment: @icYou520 Is there a particular reason it would render the preview on the gpu but not the final image?

Comment: The preview is just a quick view it doesn't take in to account all the calculations needed for your scene. When you do a final render that's when ALL the math is calculated, taking up more memory. Your preview is set to 32 and your final render is set to 200.

Comment: It looks like your memory peaked a little over 4GB. So if you only have 4GB of ram on your GPU thats why it would give you the error. This usually happens to me when I use a lot of hi res textures. But it could be a number of things.

Comment: @icYou520 So it turns out that it did eventually render using CPU but I am a little confused to as why my GPU was using all 4GB to render what appears to be a relatively simple scene. Thanks

Comment: There are too many variables for me to guess without looking at your file. But things add up quickly. This might help explain a little. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27690/why-does-blender-use-so-much-memory-for-large-textures

Comment: read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61508/cycles-gpu-cuda-out-of-memory-how-to-identify-the-problem-objects

Comment: To understand the difference between the final render and preview: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2728/what-are-the-technical-differences-between-f12-render-and-viewport-preview

Comment: What you omitted in your question is any hint of the complexity of the scene. Large textures, high values on the subsurf modifier, subsurface scattering (or any kind of scattering), and a whole bunch of variables can easily push your scene beyond your compute capability. For a better anwer please upload your file.

Comment: @cegaton I apologise. I added the blend file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference and reason why it renders in previw and not in render is this setting:

[image]

In render the surface gets divided a lot more, so the geometry takes a lot of VRAM. Your scene takes 4.2 GB of it in render.

Also many other modifiers have separate settings for viewport/render, there may be objects hidden from preview etc.

Try to lower the quality till it fits in memory, or render on CPU or borrow/buy better GPU.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Just turning max subdivisions down to 4 fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

You don't have enough memory on your GPU. "CUDA Error: Out of Memory".

Try decreasing the number of vertex and/or lower the complexity of the scene.

**EDIT again**
Can you make the .blend File downloadable? 
Also, take a look at this post:
[Cycles / CUDA Error: Out of Memory](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18407/cycles-cuda-error-out-of-memory)

It may help you.

Comment: Additional samples shouldn't increase memory.

Comment: Ok, sorry for the error